# How to generate curve25519 key pair for diffie hellman algorithm?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I want to implement ECDHE algorithm in my project ,for that I want to use Curve25519.But stuck how to generate key-pair for Curve25519.With other curve I am able to generate key-pair,but for curve25519 getting algorithm not found

I tried with below code:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
        kpg.initialize(256);
        KeyPair private_Key1 = kpg.generateKeyPair();
       PublicKey ourPk1 = private_Key1.getPublic();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`BouncyCastle`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) as cryptographic provider which has support for this curve :

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.X9ECParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.ec.CustomNamedCurves;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec;

import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        X9ECParameters curveParams = CustomNamedCurves.getByName("Curve25519");
        ECParameterSpec ecSpec = new ECParameterSpec(curveParams.getCurve(), curveParams.getG(), curveParams.getN(), curveParams.getH(), curveParams.getSeed());

        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", new BouncyCastleProvider());
        kpg.initialize(ecSpec);

        KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
        PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

    }
}
```

## Extracting raw public key

To extract raw `x` and `y` of `ECPoint` (public key) you can use this code:

```
byte[] encoded = publicKey.getEncoded();
ASN1Sequence asn1Primitive = ASN1Sequence.getInstance(encoded);
ASN1Encodable algorithmIdentifier = asn1Primitive.getObjectAt(0);
DERBitString ecPointBitString = (DERBitString) asn1Primitive.getObjectAt(1);

//use curve parameters from previous code snippet
ECPoint ecPoint = curveParams.getCurve().decodePoint(ecPointBitString.getOctets());
byte[] x = ecPoint.getAffineXCoord().getEncoded();
byte[] y = ecPoint.getAffineYCoord().getEncoded();
```

This is basically parsing the encoded `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` described in [RFC5480](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5480#section-2)

## Extracting raw private key

```
BCECPrivateKey privateKey1 = (BCECPrivateKey) privateKey;
byte[] bigIntPk = privateKey1.getS().toByteArray();
```

or by parsing DER objects :

```
ASN1Sequence instance = ASN1Sequence.getInstance(privateKey.getEncoded());
DEROctetString pkOctetString = (DEROctetString) instance.getObjectAt(2);

ASN1Sequence ecPkSequence = DERSequence.getInstance(pkOctetString.getOctets());
DEROctetString pkOctets = (DEROctetString) ecPkSequence.getObjectAt(1);

byte[] bigIntPk = new BigInteger(1, pkOctets.getOctets()).toByteArray();
```

Comment: Just curious, in the above snippet the `publicKey.getEncoded()` has length of 309 bytes and `privateKey.getEncoded()` is 587 bytes. Whereas, in the `libsodium` Curve25519 the public and private keys both have 32 bytes lengths. Any comments on this?

Comment: @eigenfield Yes, actually with `publicKey.getEncoded()`  you will get entire SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure encoded and with `privateKey.getEncoded()` you will get entire `PrivateKeyInfo` structure encoded in DER. For getting raw 32 bytes curve parameters you would have to parse it with DER parser for example.

Comment: Hi @MichałKrzywański, I was looking for a way to get raw 32 bytes public and private key (generated by Curve25519) and find your suggestion "parse it with DER parser for example" could you elaborate more on that? any link or example would be appreciated.

Comment: @MehrdadNoroozi I updated the answer on how to extract x and y of public key. To do the same for private key you should refer to RFC documents where this structure is described and decode it similiary.

Comment: Or cast `publicKey` to its type `org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.BCECPublicKey` or implemented interface `java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey` and call `getW` to get the `ECPoint`

Answer (score 8):

Curve25519 [seems supported](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/324) from Java 11 onwards (note that the standard Java follows the OpenJDK Java nowadays).

The linked to JEP (Java Enhancement Proposal) also contains sample code, included here verbatim:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("XDH");
NamedParameterSpec paramSpec = new NamedParameterSpec("X25519");
kpg.initialize(paramSpec); // equivalent to kpg.initialize(255)
// alternatively: kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("X25519")
KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();

KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("XDH");
BigInteger u = ...
XECPublicKeySpec pubSpec = new XECPublicKeySpec(paramSpec, u);
PublicKey pubKey = kf.generatePublic(pubSpec);

KeyAgreement ka = KeyAgreement.getInstance("XDH");
ka.init(kp.getPrivate());
ka.doPhase(pubKey, true);
byte[] secret = ka.generateSecret();
```

Note that the public key generated by the key factory is the one from the other party. Usually you would decode that value from bytes though.

Comment: If you're still stuck on an older Java version: do you really want to execute security related code on an old version? Disclaimer: I haven't tried above code yet.

Comment: Maarten, ss long as the old version is still officially supported it should be just as secure as the new version, more or less.

Comment: True, so using Java 8 LTS seems an option, except if you need this kind of new functionality. In general, I hope that non-portable Java code is more or less a thing of the past. Although project managers may of course use any excuse to speed up development. Those project managers should be kicked out of their function though, 60% or more of time spend in software is during maintenance.